# SQL Machine Learning using matrix multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-regression

What is the easiest classification algorithm in SQL when my data looks like this?

```
A = 101000101110
B = 010101110010
C = 100101101000
B = 100101101101
C = 100010000001
A = 100010010101
```

These are binary vectors that indicate the presence of a certain attribute.

I was thinking about training some kind of regression using python that gives me a vector.

Then I would only need to multiple the vector with the binary vectors and I would bet some number indicating me what kind of label I have using a threshold method.

Are there any python algorithms that allow me to do that?

Comment: Unless SQL has changed in the last 10 years and I missed it, SQL doesn't have machine learning algorithms... It's a language for specifying a query out of a database.  I suspect you might need to reword your question

Comment: The question, the data, and the goal are all unclear to me.  @Ohumeronen, please review this article on "How do I ask a good question?" and revise your post accordingly:  https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  You are more likely to get the help you need if you help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few overlapping topics here:

1. Fitting a model to your data in Python
2. Storing model parameters to the database
3. Executing SQL queries to apply the model

I would start with a linear model, such as [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) or [linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis).

You should think carefully how you structure the data in the database. This is more of a programming topic, but I would have a table with few columns and several rows to represent each item. This way you don't need to modify the schema if your data gets a new input feature.

Then as a final step you'll need to "just" write the SQL query, joining attribute data and model parameters and output. But this is off-topic on an AI forum.

Getting back to linear regression, you must re-arrange the binary representations into separate columns:

```
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```